# `Show` instance for GHC core

Tags: haskell, ghc

I am trying to work with GHC core data types.
I am able to compile my Haskell source to core representation with type `Bind CoreBndr`.
As we know there is no default `Show` instance for this data type.
There is a way to pretty print this representation but it has way too much noise associated with it.
I want to treat GHC core as any other algebraic data type and write functions with it.
It would be much easier if we had a `Show` instance of GHC core.
Has anybody already written a show instance which I can reuse?

Aside, how does the community write and verify programs that deal with GHC core?

Comment: What kind of noise are you talking about?

Comment: The output from `ghc -c file.hs -ddump-simpl` gives core representation of the program pertty printed with explicit types, dictionary arguments occurance checks etc. but in a program context the core representation is just a value of some data type.

Comment: The primary purpose of core is not to be pretty printed; it is an internal, low level language whose design is largely for the benefit of the compiler, not the human programmer. However, "I want to treat GHC core as any other algebraic data type and write functions with it" - this is already precisely the case. Core is literally just a Haskell ADT - what leads you to believe otherwise? Note that there is a [pretty printer for core](https://www.stackage.org/haddock/lts-8.2/ghc-8.0.2/PprCore.html) in the GHC api already.

Comment: How would a `Show` instance help you to "treat GHC core as any other algebraic data type and write functions with it"?

Comment: @user2407038 I know GHC core is ADT but while writing transformations for the same it is easier if i get the show representation. Pretty printer doesnt really tell me the the structure of the value in terms of constructors, variables and literals.

Comment: @DanielWagner show instance will tell me the structure of the value which will help me validate the changes I am doing and will also tell me the cases i need to handle via pattern matching etc.

Comment: @ankitrokdeonsns If you just want a rough show instance for the purpose of debugging, then you could e.g. use the `Data (Expr b)` instance to call [`gshow`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/syb-0.6/docs/Data-Generics-Text.html). Alternatively, just write your own `Show` instance which shows core how *you* want; `gshow` will actually be much nosier than `pprCoreExpr`. Although, I don't see how a `Show` instance allows one to do the things you want ("validate the changes I am doing" and "tell me the cases i need to handle via pattern matching").

Comment: @user2407038 My original intention for this `Show` instance is for debugging purposes only. The output from `gshow` is ALMOST what I want. The only problem it has is  for `Var` data constructor it just gives `{abstract: Var}` in the result which is not very useful for my debugging. Great suggestion though.

Comment: Use `:i` in ghci to learn more about the type.

Answer (score 0):

A naive implementation of `Show` in GHC is probably not what you want. The reason for this is because internally GHC has recursion among many of its data types. For instance, between [TyCon](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.1/src/TyCon.html#TyCon), [AlgTyConRhs](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.1/src/TyCon.html#AlgTyConRhs), and [DataCon](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/libraries/ghc-8.0.1/src/DataCon.html#DataCon) we have:

`TyCon` has `AlgTyCon`, which contains `AlgTyConRhs`.

`AlgTyConRhs` contains `data_cons :: [DataCon]` as one of its record fields.

`DataCon` contains `dcRepTyCon :: TyCon` as one of its fields.

And thus we come full circle. Because of how `Show` works, recursion like this will create infinite output if you ever attempt to print it.

In order to get a "nice" custom representation with data constructors and everything showing, you would have to write it yourself. This is actually somewhat challenging, since you have to consider and debug cases of recursion like this that default pretty printers have solved.

Comment: There is no fundamental problem with such a circular definition of show as long as you make progress throughout the AST. Eventually you reach a terminal case and the program will terminate.